# Build error when building iPad app for UIKitForMac

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

When attempting to build an iPad app for Mac using Catalyst, I get the following error:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics(...o),
building for UIKitForMac, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator,
file '/../FirebaseAnalytics.framework/FirebaseAnalytics' for architecture x86_64
```

Is this something Google has to fix? The version is FirebaseAnalytics 6.0.1

Comment: I'm having the same issue but for Realm. I would create a ticket here if I were you: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Comment: Many libs will have to adapt in order to allow support for UIKitForMac. Firebase already has an open issue related to this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3189.

For now, I recommend you to stop linking this library and wait until the firebase team fixes it

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase libraries are not yet ported to UIKitForMac / Catalina, so it's best to conditionally compile out the usages like so:

```
#if !targetEnvironment(UIKitForMac)
...firebase code...
#endif
```

Comment: UIKitForMac was renamed to macCatalyst